# Conditional Binding in SPARQL/CONSTRUCT

Tags: sparql

I have a SPARQL CONSTRUCT that works like this:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?uri rdfs:label ?label; 
       foo:has-value ?v.        
}
WHERE {
  ?uri 
     rdfs:label ?label; 
     foo:has-flag ?f.

  BIND ( IF ( ?f = 0, "Value for Zero", IF ( ?f = 1, "Value for One", '' ) ) AS ?v )
}
```

The problem is that when `?f` is neither 0 nor 1 (but still has some value) I don't want the `has-value` statement at all. With the syntax above, I get `?uri has-value ''`. It would work, if I could assign some sort of "null" to `?v`, or avoid the binding, but I cannot find anything like that in the specs.

Any solution?

**EDIT**: The [solution by Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42462762/529286) works for common graph-based queries. The case I came from involves the use of VALUES, [is more complicated](http://jena.markmail.org/search/#query:%20list%3Aorg.apache.incubator.jena-dev+page:1+mid:q3fp3ve3dgolc2cz+state:results) and I couldn't find a solution so far.

**EDIT/2**: the [error-triggering solution](http://jena.markmail.org/search/#query:%20list%3Aorg.apache.incubator.jena-dev+page:1+mid:q3fp3ve3dgolc2cz+state:results), suggested by Andy in the Jena mailing list, works fine! Another approach, which I find more readable, is [binding an unbound variable](https://github.com/tarql/tarql/issues/55) when we want to skip the original value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given feedback in the comments, here is a solution based on `OPTIONAL` that should meet all of the criteria:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?uri rdfs:label ?label; 
       foo:has-value ?v.        
}
WHERE {
  ?uri rdfs:label ?label .     
  ?uri foo:has-flag ?f.
  OPTIONAL { FILTER (?f = 0)
      BIND("Value for Zero" AS ?v)
  }
  OPTIONAL { FILTER (?f = 1)
      BIND("Value for One" AS ?v)
  }
}
```

As pointed out, this previous solution will not cover the case where there is  label, but `?f` is not 0 or 1:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?uri rdfs:label ?label; 
       foo:has-value ?v.        
}
WHERE {
  ?uri 
     rdfs:label ?label; 
     foo:has-flag ?f. 
  FILTER (?f = 0 || ?f = 1)
  BIND ( IF ( ?f = 0, "Value for Zero", IF ( ?f = 1, "Value for One", '' ) ) AS ?v )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, no. This skips ?uri(s) with ?f != (0,1) altogether, while in such cases I want to omit the has-value triple only (and keep rdfs:label or anything else). Trying with optional, but isn't working.

Comment: Well, it exposes a clear flaw in SPARQL `IF`.  If SPRQL would allow only the `then` expression, i.e. `else` is not required, then it would be a simple mater of removing that in your original query.  All these attempts are just trying to get around that deficiency.

Comment: Yes, OPTIONAL is the way to go for the question I've asked. The problem is I came from a variant of it, involving the VALUES construct, and it seems there isn't a solution for that: http://jena.markmail.org/search/#query:%20list%3Aorg.apache.incubator.jena-dev+page:1+mid:q3fp3ve3dgolc2cz+state:results

Comment: I would say IF() is fine, because it's a function and it must return something (among other things, to avoid difficulties to SPARQL implementors).

The problem is there isn't a function (or constant) returning something that means "unbound". Inside the VALUES clause you can use UNDEF, but nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky but should work with creating a blank node and then filter out those:

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?uri rdfs:label ?label; 
       foo:has-value ?v.        
}
WHERE {
  ?uri rdfs:label ?label .
  OPTIONAL { 
    ?uri foo:has-flag ?f.

    BIND ( IF ( ?f = 0, "Value for Zero", 
             IF ( ?f = 1, "Value for One", BNODE() ) 
         ) AS ?v )
    FILTER(!ISBLANK(?v))
  }
}
```

Comment: See my comment above, this skips any triple about nodes not having 0/1.

Comment: Then put the second part into an OPTIONAL clause?